# CSS positioning woes

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and learning it side by side while making a site.

I am confused about how to position elements.I want to know whether I should use div to position elements or do I do it directly by either using tags and ids.If I use tag names and IDs I don't have to use div separately to position the elements. I can both style and position at the same time.

When to use div and when not to?

Actually, I am trying to build something like this:[image]

Comment: I think you are getting some concepts confused. I don't totally understand what you mean when you talk about using a div to position elements. A div is an element.

Comment: I accept I am not getting all the concepts properly.My question is that either I can put elements in div to position them or I can use tag names to position elements.So, which one do I use?

Comment: Very general process: Put content in divs. Give your divs class names, then position said divs using CSS referencing those class names. Google will get you far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 has made divs a bit outdated with the introduction of the header, footer, aside, section, article tags and so on. In HTML5, divs should only be used when the content cannot fit inside one of the newer, more fitting tags that I just listed. Check out this [article](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/) for better clarification.

[image: Basis HTML5 template]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question properly, it appears to me that you have a misunderstanding of some very basic concepts.

Basically, a `div` can be thought of as a Container, Panel or Element which hosts other elements. You *can* position a `div`, but chances are you're also going to want to position any other element, so here is some very basic code:

Positioning an element:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="uniqueDiv">
            <!-- You cannot use the same ID on any element more than once on a page. If you need multiple elements with the same "id", use class instead. -->

            <img id="one" src="one.png" />
            <img id="two" src="two.png" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; border: 0; outline: none; border: none; }

uniqueDiv img {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#one {
    float: left;
}

#two {
    float: right;
}
```

The is the basic premise behind positioning. I did not add an example for Padding, but you should not position elements using Padding. You should use margin instead. Also, the line that begins with `*` is called a CSS Reset and the goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins etc.

Here's a brief explanation of what this code does:

The top piece of code is obviously HTML. It should be placed in its own .html file. The bottom piece, the CSS, should be placed in its own .css file.

So, we have 1 div and two images inside it. In this scenario, we want to have one image to the far left of the div and another to the far right. We also want to push both images *down* by about 10 pixels (positioning).

So, `uniqueDiv img {}` is used to position all images contained within the uniqueDiv down by 10 pixels from the top of its div. `#one {}` and `#two` are used to float the image to the left and the right.

Answer (score 1):

My advice as per the excellent book "The Truth About HTML5 by Luke Stevens" switching to "Sections" "Header", "Footer", "Aside" etc can have accessibility problems as HTML5 is not recognized by all devices so to combat this you can make use of ARIA "Roles". You can still use Divs and assign "Roles" for your layouts, but adopting the HTML5 approach is what I would do.

Some good info is here;

[Improving Web Accesibility](http://www.webteacher.ws/2012/04/16/improve-accessibility-in-html5-with-wai-aria-landmark-roles/)

[Aria Roles 101](http://www.webteacher.ws/2010/10/14/aria-roles-101/)

Comment: It's good that you all are giving advices. But the problem is that some are the ones which require long term effort which I will definitely do later.But , now I have to focus on the work in hand and I don't have time for much studying, changes or overhaul.

Comment: Also, this is for a minor project for my college.For the time being I have to show them something.So, I don't have much time.I accept my approach is wrong but this is not my top priority right now.I will definitely look into proper web designing when I have time.